# ESP-IDF components directories errors

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, espressif-idf, esp-idf-sys

I'm having error to compile my project inside the Espresssif IDE.
The errors were like this :

```
Building in: C:\Espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4.3\mesh_network\build
Configuring in: C:\Espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4.3\mesh_network\build
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4.3\tools\cmake\toolchain-esp32s3.cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCCACHE_ENABLE=1 -DIDF_TARGET=esp32s3 C:\Espressif\frameworks\esp-idf-v4.4.3\mesh_network
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32s3-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32s3-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32s3-elf-gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32s3-elf/esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32s3-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32s3-elf-g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Git: C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe --cd-to-home  

**CMake Error at C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.3/tools/cmake/component.cmake:425 (message):
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v4.4.3/mesh_network/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Called idf_component_register from a non-component directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (idf_component_register)**
```

I tried writing the directories for the components inside the CMakeList.txt but it still didn't work. Why is that?

Thank you.